# How to set the background of a column for specific row to different color

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am populating the GridView from code-behind. The `Due Date` (Format: `mm-dd-yyyy`) is displayed for each row entry.

How can I modify the above so I can add the following: `<asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="1%" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />` (another column) between `asp:TemplateField` and `asp:HyperLinkField` where it will see if today is past the due date from the `Due Date` column. If it is past the due date, set the background to `#C000000` of that columns for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, definitely you need to change conditions

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
//Check if it is not header or footer row
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
             e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 1)
 e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to accomplish this during the databinding of the GV.

Comment: yes, you have event call yourTasksGV_RowDataBound for Databound. Also you are looking for specific column just change Cells[#]

Comment: I opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358744/how-to-prevent-postback-from-a-imagebutton-inside-a-gridview-which-is-inside-an