# How to prevent postback from a ImageButton inside a GridView which is inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have the following asp.net code: https://www.protectedtext.com/mytext90909 (password: 123)

Code-behind: https://www.protectedtext.com/mytext90908 (password: 123)

JS: https://www.protectedtext.com/mytext90907 (password: 123)

When the page loads, the GridView is populated from a Sql query. Any row, with the column `Due Date`, where today is past the the due date, is changed to red font color.

When I click on the `btnShowDepend`, I see the `Second Time` MessageBox and the GridView reloads but the forecolor of the past due date changes to black (default color).

How can I modify the codes so when the `btnShowDepend` button is clicked, it doesn't postback and just shows the popup and the forecolor does not change.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to post the code here?  That site makes it really hard to read the markup

Comment: It is a lot of codes to post here. I can still post here :)

Comment: You have server side code attached to that button.  You have to do a postback.  You can ajaxify that bad boy if you want to keep it from messing up the rest of your page.

Comment: Please help me... I thought having an UpdatePanel would fix that but Alas! i am mistaken.